# regular expression to translate header function in obj-c to c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, regex

hi I'm translating a project from obj-c to c++.
I have seen that no automated tools make this.
step by step I'm using regular expression to translate parts of the project.
I tryed to use

```
\-\((.*)\)(.*);
```

to translate `-(void)initNamesPlist; in void initNamesPlist();`
but this matches even

```
-(void)shuffle:(int[])mazzo numberOfCards:(int)n;
```

so I tryed `\-\((.*)\)([^:]*);` but this matches everything in the project...

how can I match functions without argument?
however there is a better way to translate the project?
thanks

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler#LLVM

Comment: Yes, you can use LLVM to convert code from any language LLVM supports to C. Note that the generated C code will be very low level (all loops are lowered to gotos, etc) and not very pretty (comments are stripped, original source formatting is totally lost, variables are renamed, expressions are regrouped)...I try to translate with that...hope it works